# Why does `git diff` not work with process substitution?

Tags: git, bash, git-diff

Why does `git diff` not work with process substitution?

```
$ echo hallo > hallo
$ echo holla > holla

$ git diff hallo holla  # works

$ git diff hallo <(cat holla)  # works not

diff --git a/hallo b/hallo
deleted file mode 100644
index 4cf5aa5..0000000
--- a/hallo
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1 +0,0 @@
-hallo
diff --git a/dev/fd/63 b/dev/fd/63
new file mode 120000
index 0000000..864a6ca`
```

Same with `git diff --no-index`.

It works with plain `diff`. `cat` is only a trivial example, can be replaced by a non-trivial `sed` expression.

Workaround:

```
$ cat holla | git diff hallo -  # works
```

But it will not work if both arguments should be affected by process substitution, like described in many examples for diff and process substitution.

Comment: `$cat holla | git diff hallo` this is basically 2 commands on 1 line, hence why it works

Answer (score 43):

`git diff` does not work with process substitution because a [patch](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=141347274420939&w=2) that added handling of process substitution was ignored.

Comment: That patch was submitted (and ignored) in 2014  - and we _still_ suffer from the same lack of process substitution in 2022!

Answer (score 6):

No more "`unsupported file type`"!

Now, `git diff --no-index holla <(cat hallo)` should work, as [discussed here](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqq1qhmvw6i.fsf@gitster.g/).

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), "[`git diff --no-index`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9187b276e98762f08a96db8694eb42f8ca1ab532/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> learned to read from named pipes as if they were regular files, to allow "`git diff <(process) <(substitution)`" some shells support.

See [commit 1e3f265](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e3f26542a6ecd3006c2c0d5ccc0bae4a700f7e5), [commit df52146](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df521462f01b61314c9c18a4b58a53db0cd7bf3c), [commit 4e61e0f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e61e0f68053ff3fcca298ebd3080527e3565004), [commit 4981984](https://github.com/git/git/commit/498198453dbb8ae46becbc83a1ef0979a0eb805d) (05 Jul 2023) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9187b27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9187b276e98762f08a96db8694eb42f8ca1ab532), 17 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`diff --no-index`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e3f26542a6ecd3006c2c0d5ccc0bae4a700f7e5): support reading from named pipes
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> In some shells, such as bash and zsh, it's possible to use a command substitution to provide the output of a command as a file argument to another process, like so:
>
> ```
> diff -u <(printf "a\nb\n") <(printf "a\nc\n")
> ```
>
> However, this syntax does not produce useful results with "[`git diff  --no-index`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1e3f26542a6ecd3006c2c0d5ccc0bae4a700f7e5/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup>".
> On macOS, the arguments to the command are named pipes under /dev/fd, and '`git diff`' doesnt know how to handle a named pipe.
> On Linux, the arguments are symlinks to pipes, so `git diff` helpfully diffs these symlinks, comparing their targets like "`pipe:[1234]`" and "`pipe:[5678]`".
>
> To address this "`diff --no-index`" is changed so that if a path given on the commandline is a named pipe or a symbolic link that resolves to a named pipe then we read the data to diff from that pipe.
> This is implemented by generalizing the code that already exists to handle reading from stdin when the user passes the path "`-`".
>
> If the user tries to compare a named pipe to a directory then we die as we do when trying to compare stdin to a directory.
>
> As process substitution is not support by POSIX this change is tested by using a pipe and a symbolic link to a pipe.

---

Note: "[`git diff --no-index` -R <(one) <(two)`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7435d51bfd183d2f6fd9fc9fc20a11d413d152ac/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup>" did not work correctly, which has been corrected with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023).

See [commit 48944f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48944f214c7cd7402e70e661cf9efb8dd118fe0c) (10 Sep 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7435d51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7435d51bfd183d2f6fd9fc9fc20a11d413d152ac), 20 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`diff --no-index`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48944f214c7cd7402e70e661cf9efb8dd118fe0c): fix -R with stdin
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Martin Storsjö</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> When `-R` is given, `queue_diff()` swaps the mode and name variables of the two files to produce a reverse diff.
> [1e3f265](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e3f26542a6ecd3006c2c0d5ccc0bae4a700f7e5) ("diff --no-index: support reading from named pipes", 2023-07-05, Git v2.42.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9187b276e98762f08a96db8694eb42f8ca1ab532) listed in [batch #11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e238546dc7a232d8998f1cd1ec9d3f4a0add68b)) added variables that indicate whether files are special, i.e named pipes or `-` for stdin.
> These new variables were not swapped, though, which broke the handling of stdin with with `-R`.
> Swap them like the other metadata variables.

Answer (score 2):

`git diff` cannot be used as a substitute for `diff`.  It does not diff between two arbitrary files on disk *EXCEPT* when you're outside of a Git repository *or* you pass in the `--no-index` flag.

```
$ git diff --no-index holla hallo
diff --git a/holla b/hallo
index 5cf9d44..ba1a6c1 100644
--- a/holla
+++ b/hallo
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-holla
+hallo
+new line

$ cat hallo | git diff --no-index holla -
diff --git a/holla b/-
index 5cf9d44..0000000 100644
--- a/holla
+++ b/-
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-holla
+hallo
+new line
```

This all works because `git diff` is just reading from STDIN, and that's so standard they'd have to work hard to make it not work.

As for process substitution...

```
$ git diff --no-index holla <(cat hallo)
error: /dev/fd/63: unsupported file type
fatal: cannot hash /dev/fd/63
```

What I can interpret from that is Git is trying to run its hash algorithm on the named pipe, without which Git cannot operate, and refusing because it's not a file, it's a pipe.  There's no reason to have a pipe in a Git repository, so there's no reason for `git diff` to support them.

It's a bad idea to use `git diff` as replacement for `diff`.  Git is a content tracker which works on files, not a general purpose diff tool.  This "I'm going to silently sort of work like diff outside a Git repository" is one of those overly flexible design choices that just confuses users.

Comment: "It's a bad idea to use git diff as replacement for diff." I have had diff aliased to "git diff --no-index" for many years, and it is much nicer 99% of the time. There are only occasional edge cases like this process substitution issue.